# ln(z) as antiderivative of 1/z

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

When integrating 
$$\frac{1}{x}$$
(where $x \in \mathbb{R} $) one gets
$$ln|x|+c$$
since for $x>0$ 
$$(ln|x|+c)'=(ln(x)+c)'=\frac{1}{x}$$
and for $x<0$
$$(ln|x|+c)'=(ln(-x)+c)'=\frac{1}{-x}(-1)=\frac{1}{x}$$

So my first question is: Why do I read everywhere that the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}=ln(x)$?

Secondly, when assuming $z \in \mathbb{C}$, we defined in lecture 
$$Ln_\phi(z)=ln|z|+i\varphi, \varphi \in (\phi,\varphi+2\pi]$$ 
where $\varphi=arg(z)$.

Question is:
$$\int{\frac{1}{z}dz}=?$$
If I would just pretend like $z \in \mathbb{C}$ that would result in
$$\int{\frac{1}{z}dz}=Ln_\phi|z|=ln|z|$$
or it's
$$\int{\frac{1}{z}dz}=Ln_\phi(z)=ln|z|+i\varphi$$
Obiviously, the two "solutions" are not equal in general so I wonder which one (or neither one) is correct and why.

Thanks!

**Edit 1**

$\frac{1}{z}=[z=x+iy]=\frac{1}{x+iy}=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$, so be $u(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $v(x,y)=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$. 
$$u_x=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
and
$$v_y=-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
so the first equation $u_x=v_y$ is fullfilled for $x\neq0,y\neq0$.
$$u_y=-\frac{2yx}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
and
$$v_x=\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
therefore $u_y=-v_x$ for again $x\neq0, y\neq0$, which eventually results in $\frac{1}{z}$ being holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$

**Edit 2**

Consider 
$$\int_\gamma{\frac{z}{z^2+2}dz}$$
where $\gamma$ is a line integral from $z=i$ to $z=i+2\pi$ not containing $z=\pm \sqrt{2}i$, which means in a fitting area the integral is not path-dependent and can therefore be evaluated as
$$\int_i^{2\pi}{\frac{z}{z^2+2}dz}$$
Now I'd need a antiderivative of $\frac{z}{z^2+2}$;is the solution then
$$\int_i^{2\pi}{\frac{z}{z^2+2}dz}=\frac{1}{2}ln(z^2+2)$$
or
$$\int_i^{2\pi}{\frac{z}{z^2+2}dz}=\frac{1}{2}ln|z^2+2|$$?

Comment: By $\int\frac 1zdz$, do you mean a holomorhpic function $f$ defined somewhere so that $f' = \frac 1z$?

Comment: Where did you read that the antiderivative of $1/x$ is $\ln x$? Every math textbook I ever saw said that the antiderivative is $\ln|x|$, as it should be...

Comment: @John: By $\frac{1}{z} $ I mean a function which is the inverse of the identity thus holomorphic in C \{0}

Comment: Yes, but want does $\int \frac{1}{z} dz$ mean?

Comment: @John antiderivative of $\frac{1}{z}$ such that $f'=\frac{1}{z}$

Comment: So what is the domain of $f$? It cannot be $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @John see post edit

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a holomorphic function $f$ so that $f'(z) = \frac 1z$. However, $f$ cannot be defined on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$: If $f$ is defined at $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ consider two ways of evaluating the line integral

$$\int_\gamma \frac 1z dz, $$

where $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$ for $t\in [0,2\pi]$. On the one hand,

$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z} dz = \int_0^{2\pi} i dt = 2\pi i \neq 0$$

while

$$\int_\gamma f'(z) dz = f(\gamma(2\pi))- f(\gamma(0)) = 0$$

by the fundamental theorem calculus. So to find an antiderivative of $\frac 1z$, we need to specify a branch. In that case, $Ln (z)$ will be one choice.

Comment: last integral: shouldn't it be $f(\gamma(0))$? If so I think I get what you want to say: If a antiderivative $f$ exists such that $f'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ the value of the two integrals should be equal. Does that have anything to do with the fact that $Ln(z)$ isn't injective because of the $2\pi i$-periodicity? Back to my original question: See Edit 2

Comment: @VGD: You are right, edited.