# If a function has an antiderivative, its complex integral around a circle will be $0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm reading a [proof of uniqueness of Laurent Series](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjwv6zzrsrQAhXFfpAKHTyoDSMQFgg1MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fusers.drew.edu%2Fcapelian%2FSAMPLE%2520PAGES%2520from%2520Real%2520and%2520Complex%2520Analysis.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEdSEOZ3AKkgOLnafbvGaneaBh7kA&sig2=izbUlqX98oMQuj3aZ1Kv2Q&cad=rja) for a function. 
At page $4$, it says the following:

[image]

Did you understand why the integrals vanish? It says that it's because they have antiderivatives within $N_{R_1}(z_0)$ (what is $N_{R_1}(z_0)$?)

Comment: Yes, any function with a primitive integrates to zero around a closed curve. This follows from the fact that $(F\circ \sigma)'=(F'\circ  \sigma)\sigma'$ and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff but this will happen even if there singularities? For example, $\int \frac{1}{z}$  around a circle is $2i\pi$ but $\frac{1}{z}$ has an antiderivative

Comment: It should be an antiderivative inside $N_{R_1}(z_0)$? What is this $N$?

Comment: Yes, it will happen regardless of the underlying domain. As I said, this is a consequence of FTC. It is quite elementary, and you should review it if it makes you doubt, given you've already ventured into complex analysis.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs $1/z$ does not have an antiderivative. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154321/lnz-as-antiderivative-of-1-z

Comment: @PedroTamaroff What you wrote is unclear. If $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $U$ a simply connected open, then [$\int_\gamma f(z)dz = 0$ for any closed curve $\gamma \subset U$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem). It also proves that $g(z) = \int_a^z f(s)ds$ is well-defined (it doesn't depend on the path $a \to z$) so that $g'(z) = f(z)$ i.e. $f(z)$ has a holomorphic anti-derivative on $U$. Finally, it fails for$ f(z) = 1/z$ because $U = \{z,0 <|z| < 1\}$ is **not** simply connected.

Comment: @user1952009 What I wrote is clear: if $f=F'$ for some $F$, then $\int_\gamma f=0$ for any closed curve $\gamma$. If $n>1$, then $z^{-n}$ admits a primitive, whence the claim in the OPs quoted text.